# Azure Function gives "The token has an invalid signature" only AFTER request is sent

Tags: python, pycharm, azure-functions, azureservicebus, signature

I'm trying to run an http trigger azure function made in Python that queues up some tasks for the service bus.

I'm running it locally.

The bizarre issue is that the EVAL_SERVICE_BUS field in local.settings.json file is correct, and the function starts successfully. If you put the wrong token, the function will give an exception instead and shut down.

However, only AFTER I sent a request to my function it starts attempting to authenticate a few times and then stops after # of attempts limit is reached.

Why is the token accepted at function start but declined when I send the request?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! could you please share some code?